# check if column have duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and i am trying to mutate a new column and give 1,0 to duplicate found.
for example i have data frame like below

```
df4 <- data.frame(emp_id =c("DEV-2962","KTN_2252","ANA2719","ITI_2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","DEV2698","ITI2535","DEV2698","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  email = c("akash.dev@abcd.com","rahul.singh@abcd.com","salman.abbas@abcd.com","ram.lal@abcd.com","ram.lal@xyz.com","prabal.garg@xyz.com","sanu.ali@abcd.com","kunal.singh@abcd.com","lakhan.tomar@abcd.com","praveen.thakur@abcd.com","sarman.ali@abcd.com","zuber.khan@dkl.com","giriraj.singh@dkl.com","lokesh.sharma@abcd.com","pooja.pawar@abcd.com","nikita.sharma@abcd.com"))
```

now i am mutating a new column for highlight duplicates.

```
ID = "emp_id"
Email = "email"

ID <- sym(ID)
Email <- sym(email)

df4 <- df4 %>% filter(!is.na(!!Email)) %>% group_by(!!Email) %>%
   mutate(Flag=1:n(),`Duplicate_email`=ifelse(Flag==1,0,1)) %>% select(-Flag) %>% ungroup(.)
```

but this creating a new column with email, and I wanted to have a new column and for duplicate found give 1 to mutated column.

Comment: Can you please show the expected output for your sample input?

Comment: The reason  why your code doesnt work as expected it's because you wrote `Email <- sym(email)` instead of `Email <- sym(Email)`. If you change it this way, a new column will not be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `duplicated` function which does what you want:

```
##
ID = "emp_id"
Email = "email"

ID <- sym(ID)
Email <- sym(Email) ## match the variable name above

df4 <- df4 %>% filter(!is.na(!!Email)) %>%
   mutate(`Duplicate_email` = as.integer(duplicated(!!Email)))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Code Review

Here you can see where your mistake was.

```
library(dplyr)

ID = "emp_id"
Email = "email"

ID <- sym(ID)
Email <- sym(Email) ## you wrote: Email <- sym(email)

df4 %>%
  filter(!is.na(!!Email)) %>% 
  group_by(!!Email) %>%
  mutate(Flag=1:n(),
         `Duplicate_email`= ifelse(Flag==1,0,1)) %>% 
  select(-Flag) %>% 
  ungroup(.)
```

### Simplification

Your code can be simplified in this way.

It's more compact, readable and fast, but it gets exactly the same result.

```
df4 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(!!Email)) %>% 
  mutate(Duplicate_email = +duplicated(!!Email))
```